# Evaluate $\sum_{r=1}^{m} \frac{(r-1)m^{r-1}}{r\cdot\binom{m}{r}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-coefficients, telescopic-series

Evaluate:$$\sum_{r=1}^{m} \frac{(r-1)m^{r-1}}{r\cdot\binom{m}{r}}$$

Using the property:$$r\binom{m}{r}=m\binom{m-1}{r-1}$$

It is same as  $$\sum_{r=2}^{m} \frac{(r-1)m^{r-1}}{m\cdot\binom{m-1}{r-1}}$$

How I do now?

Comment: Right from the beginning we have $\sum\limits_{r=\color{red}1}^{m} \frac{(r-1)m^{r-1}}{r\cdot\binom{m}{r}}=\sum\limits_{r=\color{red}2}^{m} \frac{(r-1)m^{r-1}}{r\cdot\binom{m}{r}}$

Comment: @callculus yes you are right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $$S=\sum_{r=1}^{m} \frac{(r-1)m^{r-1}}{r\cdot\binom{m}{r}}$$

Multiply both sides by $m+1$.

$$S(m+1)=\sum_{r=1}^{m} \frac{(m+1)(r-1)m^{r-1}}{r\cdot\binom{m}{r}}$$

$$S(m+1)=\sum_{r=1}^{m} \frac{(mr-(m-r+1))m^{r-1}}{r\cdot\binom{m}{r}}$$

$$S(m+1)=\sum_{r=1}^{m} \frac{(rm^r-(m-r+1)m^{r-1})}{r\cdot\binom{m}{r}}$$

$$S(m+1)=\sum_{r=1}^{m} \frac{m^r}{\binom{m}{r}}-\frac{(m-r+1)m^{r-1}r!\cdot(m-r)!}
{r\cdot m!} $$

$$S(m+1)=\sum_{r=1}^{m} \frac{m^r}{\binom{m}{r}}-\frac{m^{r-1}(m-r+1)!(r-1)!}{m!}$$

$$S(m+1)=\sum_{r=1}^{m} \frac{m^r}{\binom{m}{r}}-\frac{m^{r-1}}{\binom{m}{r-1}}$$

Now this becomes a  telescoping series.

$$\boxed {S(m+1)=m^m-1}$$

Comment: Does my comment answer your question? Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @callculus yes you were right,how did you do  then?

Comment: Then I´ve done nothing. For me it looks o.k. what you´ve done.